# Finding a joint probability density function over a shaded region

Tags: statistics

I've only recently been getting the hang of finding joint PDFs, but today I encountered and attempted a question that really had me thinking for a while:

"The joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is zero outside of the red-shaded region. Note that the line that divides the red-shaded region from the white region is given by $y = 0.5+2(x-0.5)^2$.

[The graph in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1y1X.png)

Find the joint probability density function $X$ and $Y$ over the red-shaded region."

This is my attempt at the question:

$
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0.5+2(x-0.5)^2-y, & \text{if 0≤x≤1, 0≤y≤1,} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$

While this sort of makes sense to me, it also feels a bit wrong because from what I remember from integral calculus, $Y$ is clearly being limited by the aforementioned function.

Furthermore, the next question asks to find the marginal PDF of $Y$ which ends up being $\frac{2}{3}-y$ which just looks wrong.

Any thoughts/tips?

Comment: I think there's some information missing.  If $f(y)=\frac23-y$, then $y<\frac23$, but I don't see why that should be from your diagram.

Comment: Is the joint density assumed constant in the red region? [i.e. uniform distribution over red part]? If so begin by finding area of that region.

Comment: The marginal PDF is definitely wrong.